# jQuery spinner not working with jQuery UI 1.7.2

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Spinner

The demos in the doc reference the following javascript file:
http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.6rc2/ui/ui.core.js

However, when i use jquery ui 1.7.2 core.js it doesn't function. Other parts of the web application depend on 1.7.2.

Any help with this issue would be much appreciated as i've been stuck on this for some time now.

Thanks in advance.

Shawn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spinner plugin was removed following 1.6.2rc2 along with autocomplete and the color plugin. For more information see (where it refers to 1.6.3 which, a few patches later, became 1.7)...

http://blog.jquery.com/2008/12/11/whats-up-with-jquery-ui/

http://blog.jquery.com/2009/02/12/jquery-ui-17-is-the-new-16/

> The 1.6rc3 release is being wrapped up
>   and will be out within a week. Our
>   goal is to have 1.6 final out still in
>   December. We’ve decided to cut back
>   the number of new additions in order
>   to re-factor the existing plugins for
>   improved accessibility, performance,
>   and theming. In this release, the only
>   new plugin will be the determinate
>   progress bar. The autocomplete,
>   colorpicker, and spinner plugins have
>   been moved into a future release (to
>   allow time for further refactoring,
>   not delaying 1.6 any further), while
>   magnifier has been moved into
>   experimental again, soon to be
>   released as external plugin at Paul
>   Bakaus’ homepage (more on that in the
>   next final release announcement). With
>   a better planning process in place now
>   (see below), we’re confident removing
>   plugins from a release candidate won’t
>   happen in the future, and we apologize
>   for any trouble it might have
>   introduced for you.